# Despeckle not working properly

Tags: denoise, depth-map, compositing-nodes

When i am using despeckle in the compositing tab to clean up a depth pass it just slightly reduces the noise. In the video I am watching one despeckle already works better than 6 for me.

first picture is how it is supposed to look with 3 despeckles, 2nd is mine
[image: how it is supposed to look with 3 despeckles]

[image: how it looks for me]

Comment: Does Denoise work better than Despeckle here?

Comment: it doesn't work at all on the depth map